# Draw Bubble Graph in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, bubble-chart

hope you guys are doing well.

How can I draw graph similar to below image?

[image]

To be more specific, my graph will have low, normal and high risk with orange, green and red colours respectively. Each containing bubble with info in x- axis.

I wanna make exactly like above image any help would be appreciated and also please be specific while posting some third party libs and all.

How can I achieve the above graph?

Note- In X- axis (dates) and Y- axis [(values) in bubbles] are there.

**EDIT**
y-axis is fixed with some range by x-axis is from server took in `NSMutableArray`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UICollectionView will help you in this case...

Comment: @FahimParkar How can I achieve Y- axis / origins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step in drawing graph is to create X-Y axis layout. You can draw X and Y axis line using `UIBezierPath` and `CAShapeLayer`.

```
    UIBezierPath *graphPath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    [graphPath setLineWidth:GRAPH_LAYOUT_LINE_WIDTH];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [graphPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(ORIGN_X, ORIGN_Y)];
    [graphPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake((ORIGN_X + TOTAL_X_DIST),ORIGN_Y)];
    [graphPath stroke]; // drawing path

    //Creating graph layout
    CAShapeLayer *graphLayout = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    graphLayout.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    graphLayout.strokeColor = [GRAPH_LAYOUT_COLOR CGColor];
    graphLayout.lineWidth = GRAPH_LAYOUT_LINE_THICKNESS;
    graphLayout.path = [graphPath CGPath];
    [self.layer addSublayer:graphLayout];
```

Repeat the above code for drawing Y axis

Second you need to create X and Y axis scale

```
    float minX = 0;
    float maxX = 10;
    float minY = 0;
    float maxY = 100;

    float x1Unit = 1;
    float y1Unit = 1;

    self.spacingX = TOTAL_X_DIST/((maxX - minX)/x1Unit);
    self.spacingY = TOTAL_Y_DIST/((maxY - minY+1)/y1Unit);
```

Now you need to get the values(cartesian coordinate) of X and Y axis in an array, here i am just hard coding the points

```
//Enter the co-ordinates
    [self.pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 50)]];
    [self.pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1, 20)]];
    [self.pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(2, 35)]];
    [self.pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(3, 55)]];
    [self.pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4, 80)]];
    [self.pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5, 60)]];
    [self.pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(6, 85)]];
    [self.pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(7, 50)]];
    [self.pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(8, 30)]];
    [self.pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(9, 10)]];
    [self.pointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(10, 05)]];
```

Next we need to convert cartesian coordinate values to values of x and y with respect to parent view.

```
// Creating (x,y) points based on superview coordinate system
    for (NSValue *point in self.pointsArray)
    {
        CGPoint coordinate;
        coordinate.x = (STARTING_X*x1Unit + ([point CGPointValue].x * self.spacingX) + self.spacingX/1.5)/x1Unit;
        coordinate.y = (STARTING_Y*y1Unit - ([point CGPointValue].y * self.spacingY))/y1Unit;

        [self.coordinateArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:coordinate]];

    }
```

Now it's time to add beautiful bubbles

```
for (int a = 0; a < [self.coordinateArray count]; a++)
{
    CGPoint point = [[self.coordinateArray objectAtIndex:a] CGPointValue];

//Creating bubble for points on the graph.
UIView *bubble = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:BUBBLE_FRAME];
bubble.Layer.cornerRadius = BUBBLE_FRAME_WIDTH/2;

//Giving the color for the bubble based on the Y-Axis value
if (point.y <= 50)
{
    bubble.backgroundColor = RED_COLOR;
}
else if (point.y > 50 && point.y <= 80)
{
    bubble.backgroundColor = YELLOW_COLOR;
}
else
{
    bubble.backgroundColor = GREEN_COLOR;
}

[self addSubview:bubble]; 
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. what about (Y-Axis range) background colours of Graph?

Comment: Y- Axis range : can be height of the screen or any percentage of it required.
`TOTAL_Y_DIST = self.frame.size.height - STARTING_Y`

Once you get the Y-Axis based on the range you can create two UIViews and give them separate background color.

Comment: Could you please elaborate BUBBLE_FRAME?

Comment: If you want bubble of radius 50 points then create a UIView with width and height of 50 pt and then give the corner radius of the bubble view as 50/2 you will get a circle shape view.

Comment: For more graphs check this https://github.com/Sunil-RZT/iosGraphKit

Comment: @SunilRao What is GRAPH_LAYOUT_LINE_WIDTH, ORIGN_X , TOTAL_X_DIST,ORIGN_Y, STARTING_Y

Comment: @abha 
GRAPH_LAYOUT_LINE_WIDTH -> Line width of axis line
(ORIGN_X, ORIGN_Y) -> Origin
TOTAL_X_DIST -> Total X axis width
STARTING_Y -> Starting value of Y point with respect to screen size